# The system message theme is...jarring

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, system-message

Here's what I mean.  Take this vanilla screenshot:

[image]

That beige bar is stretching across the entire site.  Not a fan.

Now, 99 times out of 100, that banner is there to tell me that SO is in read-only mode.  But the one time that the site is usable, it still feels like it isn't.

There's a couple of things I propose for a better user experience:

- Move the banner to below the black banner (at the very top)
- Change the color according to the context of the message (blue for slightly more "generic" announcements, like this, and red for offline notices)

Here are two examples.

Blue:

[image]

Red:

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's *supposed to be* jarring. You're supposed to *notice* it.

We don't use these things very often; in fact, we use them less now than we used to, reserving them for major, potentially-disruptive events. And when an event has the potential to disrupt your normal use of the site, it is *critical* that you're aware of it.

Comment: I agree with this - I don't see them nearly as often as I did a couple of years back.  But, I would counter that the red themed suggestion is just as jarring.  Again, I base this off of the fact that those banners typically mean that I can't use the site; I feel that the color coding conveys that message clearer.